# Template engine for single PHP page with structured content?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, slim

I'm planning to build a single PHP web page that will contain lots of structured data in nested divs, spans, bootstrap elements etc., like:

- Hardware

  - Notebooks

    - HP
    - Apple
    - Dell
  - Tablets

    - Apple
    - Samsung
- Software

  - Operating Systems

    - Windows 10
    - ...

The list ist really long with far more than 100 elements. The elements will change from time to time, but the structure will be the same for all elements and sub-elements.

Now, I wonder if plain HTML+CSS is the best way to code this page. As the structure of the elements is always the same, so it would probably be a good idea to use templates. However, I'm not sure if I really should set up a database and some kind of PHP framework like [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com) or [Laravel](https://laravel.com)/[Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com) in order to generate the code. After all, it's just a single page without and routing, forms, login etc. So this might be too much.

Perhaps, a templating engine like [Plates](http://platesphp.com) could be the answer? But where should I store the data?

What would be your choice for such a use case? Single page with lots of structured data?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your subject line, I want to clarify something and then suggest a solution.

**PHP Components & Composer**

State of the art PHP development utilizes [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) to orchestrate component libraries.  This could be in the form of a full stack framework or in the form of just a few specific component libraries that solve the problems you have.

**Datastores**

Your sample shows data with simple hierarchy.  Certainly for ease of maintenance a datastore of some type would be helpful.  A relational database or a document database will do the job.  If that is what you want I'm going to suggest you use a specific ORM or at least a portion of it, and that ORM is Doctrine.

Why Doctrine?  Because it supports a number of the most popular open source RDBMS, and it also allows you to use it's DBAL layer without the full ORM, if you just want to implement a few simple queries.  With that said, if you have the option of using MongoDB, MongoDB collections support hierarchies very well.  A great feature of Doctrine2 is that it has support for MongoDB, which differentiates it from most other PHP ORM's.

The only real reason to go to all this trouble is that you also intend to create an administration tool that will let you maintain your hierarchical data.  If you don't, you could just as easily have a script that you include that has the data in PHP array form.

**Templating**

For templating, my suggestion is that you use Twig.  As part of the Symfony components, Twig is both self contained and part of the Symfony full stack framework.  It's robust and well designed, and has numerous features (although to be fair, Laravel's Blade has similar features in most cases) and includes [support for ESI](http://%20%20https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache/esi.html) which could be a great feature for a relatively static page like the one you describe.

Templating in twig, vs writing PHP code to do the same, lets you focus on your markup and avoid introducing a lot of PHP code that will turn your view code into spaghetti.

**Components**
The important thing is that you can simply use the few components you need to support your application, and you certainly don't need either Laravel or Symfony.  Since Symfony began its life as components (and was the foundation for the Laravel project in fact)  I'd push you towards the Symfony components, although at the end of the day, you could also utilize parts of Laravel (Blade, Eloquent) in the same way that I'm advocating you use portions of Symfony.  Symfony simply is the community and stack I prefer, and has a longer history of being used on a component basis in other projects.

**Try out the new minimal Symfony4**

Last but not least, the newest version of Symfony (Symfony 4) is really worth looking at for a number of reasons.  It essentially is now a micro framework, that comes with the bare minimum of components.  They advertise it as 70% smaller than v3.

What differentiates this release is the innovation of Symfony flex with recipes and Composer integration.  It is now built to automate a lot of the things that you might otherwise have had to figure out on your own for putting these components together into an application.

Take a look at it and see if it might help you get your application built with minimal components and minimal time spent having to learn how to make things work together.

*In summary, I'd suggest you consider*:

- [Symfony Components](https://symfony.com/components) (You might want a few more depending on your
  final solution).
- [Doctrine2](http://www.doctrine-project.org)
- [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/)
- [Symfony4](https://symfony.com/4)

Comment: Thank you very much! After looking into these components, I finally decided to use Laravel, Eloquent, Blade and possibly Backpack as an admin interface!

Comment: Haha, well I guess my selling of symfony didn't work, but really you are in good hands with either symfony or laravel components.